# R group_by: column with 3 classes A,B,C. transform any element equal to A into B or C in order to maximise the minimum frequency of B or C

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have the following dataset, where each observation  belongs to a cluster and a group

```
df <- data.frame(
  cluster = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5),
  group = c("g1", "g2", "g1", "g2", "g1", "both", "g1", "g1", "both", "both", "g1", "g2", "g1", 
            "g1", "g1", "both", "g1", "g2", "both"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

```
cluster    group
1          "g1"
1          "g2"
1          "g1"
1          "g2"
2          "g1"
2          "both"
2          "g1"
2          "g1"
3          "both"     
3          "both"
3          "g1"
3          "g2"
4          "g1"
4          "g1"
4          "g1"
4          "both" 
5          "g1"
5          "g2"
5          "both"
```

what I want to obtain is to transform any element in "group" equal to "both"  into "g1" or "g2" according to this rule:

for any cluster, the elements equal to "both" should be equal to the least frequent element. (so if in a cluster I have 4 observations labelled "g1" and 2 labelled "g2' and 2 labelled "both" I want to transform "both" into "g2").
In the case I have a cluster where there s an element equal to "g1" another equal to "g2" and two element equal to "both" I want one of them to be transformed into "g1" and the other into "g2". basically, for each cluster I want to transform the elements equal to the class "both" to maximise the minimum frequency of the two classes "g1" and "g2".

> max(min(freq(g1),freq(g2))

(if in the cluster the g1-frequency=2 while the g2-frequency=3 and I have an element = "both" I want to transform it into g1 so that g1-frequency=3)

thus, the expected result is:

```
 cluster    group
1          "g1"
1          "g2"
1          "g1"
1          "g2"
2          "g1"
2          "both"
2          "g1"
2          "g1"
3          "g1" (or "g2" )   
3          "g2" (or "g3")
3          "g1"
3          "g2"
4          "g1"
4          "g1"
4          "g1"
4          "g2" 
5          "g1"
5          "g2"
5          "g2" (or "g1")
```

I hope it s clear what my objective is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a somewhat long-winded way of doing it, but it is hopefully understandable and it works:

```
f <- function(x)
{
  n_replace <- length(which(x == "both"))
  n_g1      <- length(which(x == "g1"))
  n_g2      <- length(which(x == "g2"))
  n_diff    <- n_g1 - n_g2
  result    <- character()
  if(n_diff != 0) 
  {  
    result <- c(result, rep(ifelse(n_diff > 0, "g2", "g1"), abs(n_diff)))
    n_replace <- n_replace - n_diff
  }
  if(n_replace > 0) return(c(result, rep(c("g1", "g2"), length = n_replace)))
  result
}

df %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(group == "both", f(group), group))
```

which gives the following result:

```r
# A tibble: 19 x 2
# Groups:   cluster [5]
   cluster group
     <int> <chr>
 1       1 g1   
 2       1 g2   
 3       1 g1   
 4       1 g2   
 5       2 g1   
 6       2 g2   
 7       2 g1   
 8       2 g1   
 9       3 g1   
10       3 g2   
11       3 g1   
12       3 g2   
13       4 g1   
14       4 g1   
15       4 g1   
16       4 g2   
17       5 g1   
18       5 g2   
19       5 g1
```